# Изменение данных у экземпляров модели

Tags: django

Есть класс Vertex с некоторыми полями и класс  Profile
 с полем

```
VertexOnOrOff = ArrayField(models.IntegerField(default=()))
```

и методом save

```
def save(self,*args,**kwargs):
        self.VertexOnOrOff = [0,0]
        super().save(*args,**kwargs)
```

Как сделать так, чтобы при каждом добавлении экземпляра модели Vertex, у каждого пользователя в базе данных в массив VertexOnOrOff добавлялся 0 в конец, т.e было [0,0], стало [0,0,0]

В файле signals.py имею следующее

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.dispatch import receiver
from .models import Profile

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.profile.save()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например, переопределить метод save у модели `Vertex`

```
def save(self,*args,**kwargs):
    for user in User.objects.all():
        user.VertexOnOrOff.append(0)
        user.save(update_fields=['VertexOnOrOff'])
    super().save(*args,**kwargs)
```

Или же написать сигнал `post_save` для `Vertex`:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=Vertex)
def create_vertex(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        for user in User.objects.all():
            user.VertexOnOrOff.append(0)
            user.save(update_fields=['VertexOnOrOff'])
```

Comment: Спасибо большое

Comment: @BobKapusAkba лучшее "спасибо" - это голос за ответ и его подтверждение